# INI Parser crashes with `segmentation fault` after opening more than one section

Tags: c, parsing, memory, ini

I am making an INI parser that will save all sections in an array for later use. The problem I am running into is in `SECTION_OPEN`. I call `ini_init()` which causes the first line of the function to crash with a `Segmentation Fault`. I am known for putting many memory leaks in my code, but after looking through, I haven't figured out a way to get around this.
I have tried:

- Giving many different mallocs over 100000 to work with, which still crashes
- Commenting out code and slowly un-commenting to see what is crashing

test.ini:

```
; This is a valid comment
; Global variables work
var = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3

[Test1] ; Section
name = Primitive
organization = PrimOS
test = var
another = test
once_again=another_test

; Will check to see if variables work as intended
[.Test2] ; Subsection
; This variable will crash
another_organization = %name%

; This test will crash
[Test3] ; Section
another_name = "This is me"
```

ini.h

```
#ifndef SEAWARE_INI_H
#define SEAWARE_INI_H

#define MAX_HOLDING_CELL 255
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 255

// Syntax
#define QUOTES '"'
#define SECTION_OPEN '['
#define SUBSECTION '.'
#define SECTION_CLOSE ']'
#define VARIABLE_CALL '%'
#define COMMENT ';'
#define EQUALS '='
#define EQUALS_PTR "="

// Only one variableType for each variable
struct variable {
    char * variableName;
    char * value;
};

// The magic...
struct INI {
    // If NULL, you are global
    char * sectionName;
    // Like [.Test] or [Test1.Test]
    struct INI ** subSections;

    // Self explanitory
    struct variable ** variables;
    int subSectionsPtr;
    int variablesPtr;
    struct INI * nextSection;
    struct INI * prevSection;
};

struct INI * ini_init();
struct INI * interpret(struct INI * ini, char * filePath);

#endif
```

ini.c

```
#include <ini.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Global functions
// Sets up new struct INI * variable
struct INI * ini_init() {
    // Crashes
    struct INI * newINI = malloc(sizeof(struct INI));

    newINI->variablesPtr = 0;
    newINI->subSectionsPtr = 0;
    newINI->variables = malloc(sizeof(struct variable*)*(newINI->variablesPtr+1));
    newINI->subSections = malloc(sizeof(struct INI *)*(newINI->subSectionsPtr+1));

    *newINI->variables = NULL;
    *newINI->subSections = NULL;
    newINI->sectionName = NULL;
    newINI->nextSection = NULL;
    newINI->prevSection = NULL;

    return newINI;
}

// Interprets an INI file, with syntax defined in ../include/ini.h
struct INI * interpret(struct INI * ini, char * filePath) {
    // Loop Variables    
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    FILE * iniFile = fopen(filePath, "r");
    bool isSubsection = false;

    // Read line by line
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), iniFile)) {
        bool isComment = false;
        bool isQuoted = false;

        // A holding cell for all the bad defaults out there, stay safe out there...
        char holdingCell[MAX_HOLDING_CELL];
        int holdingCellPtr = 0;

        // For each character in line
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
            printf("%c", line[i]);
            // Prevents memory leaks in holdingCell
            holdingCell[holdingCellPtr] = '\0';

            // Interpret
            switch(line[i]) {

                // Move into section
                case SECTION_OPEN: {
                    // If you are in a subsection, get out of it
                    if (isSubsection == true) {
                        ini = ini->prevSection;
                        isSubsection = false;
                    }

                    struct INI * newSection = ini_init();
                    if (line[(i+1)]==SUBSECTION) {
                        isSubsection = true;
                        // Reallocate size of subSections array
                        ini->subSections =  realloc(ini->subSections, sizeof(struct INI *) * (ini->subSectionsPtr+1));
                        
                        // Set new subsection and enter it
                        newSection->prevSection = ini;
                        ini->subSections[ini->subSectionsPtr] = newSection;
                        ini->subSectionsPtr++;
                        ini = ini->subSections[ini->subSectionsPtr];
                        i++;
                    }
                    else {
                        // Create new section and go into it
                        newSection->prevSection = ini;
                        ini->nextSection = newSection;
                        ini = ini->nextSection;
                        ini->nextSection = NULL;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                // Set sectionName
                case SECTION_CLOSE: {
                    ini->sectionName = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(holdingCell));
                    strcpy(ini->sectionName, holdingCell);
                    break;
                }

                // Creates new variable and assigns name and value
                case EQUALS: {
                    isQuoted = true;
                    struct variable * newVar = malloc(sizeof(struct variable)*(ini->variablesPtr+6));
                    char * value = strtok(line, EQUALS_PTR);

                    // Set variableName
                    newVar->variableName = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(value));
                    strcpy(newVar->variableName, value);

                    // After EQUALS
                    value = strtok(NULL, EQUALS_PTR);

                    // Set value
                    newVar->value = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(value));
                    strcpy(newVar->value, value);
                    
                    printf("%s", value);

                    // Add variable to ini field
                    ini->variables = realloc(ini->variables, sizeof(struct variable*)*(ini->variablesPtr+1));
                    ini->variables[ini->variablesPtr] = newVar;
                    ini->variablesPtr++;
                    break;
                }
                
                // Skips to new line
                case COMMENT: {
                    isComment = true;
                    break;
                }
                
                // Gets names and values
                default: {
                    holdingCell[holdingCellPtr] = line[i];
                    holdingCellPtr++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isComment == true || isQuoted == true)
                break;
        }
    }

    // Stop reading file
    fclose(iniFile);

    // Loop back to beginning
    while(ini->prevSection != NULL) {
        ini = ini->prevSection;
    }

    // You get what you get, stop throwing a fit
    return ini;
}
```

Comment: @Barmar I went ahead and changed the '\0' to NULL, thanks for the tip

Comment: If you're crashing in `malloc()` it means something previously has corrupted the heap. Use valgrind or address sanitizer to catch problems like this.

Comment: you forgot the cast to your struct type before malloc

Comment: @Yvain if you are talking about ```(struct whatever) malloc()``` then that is considered a bad practice

Answer (score -1):

There are several `malloc`'s that call `strlen`.
`strlen` does not count the terminating zero.
`strcpy` copies the terminating zero. Since the allocated memory does not include the terminating zero, it is written outside the allocation. Something gets corrupted.
This can be fixed by allocating `strlen() + 1`
For example

```
newVar->value = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(value));
```

should be

```
newVar->value = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(value) + 1));
```

Since `sizeof(char)` is always `1`

```
newVar->value = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
```

could be used as well.

Another problem is in

```
// Reallocate size of subSections array
ini->subSections =  realloc(ini->subSections, sizeof ( ini_t*) * (ini->subSectionsPtr+1));

// Set new subsection and enter it
newSection->prevSection = ini;
ini->subSections[ini->subSectionsPtr] = newSection;

ini->subSectionsPtr++;
ini = ini->subSections[ini->subSectionsPtr];
i++;
```

there is a reallocation of `ini->subSections` using `(ini->subSectionsPtr+1)` making `ini->subSectionsPtr` the last index for `ini->subSections`.
After `ini->subSectionsPtr++`, the index in one beyond the allocation.

Moving `ini->subSectionsPtr++;` down a line so it is just before `i++;` seems to fix this issue.

Comment: You are amazing @xing, you fixed my code like a charm!